# AWS SQS FIFO in Python - deleted messages are available even after correct VisbilityTimeout

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I created an FIFO queue.
I send 10 msgs, receive them and delete them. But they are still available in queue and received again. I receive 10 msgs initially, then 5 , then 2 and then 0. "delete_message" response was also 200.

Code :

```
import json
import os
import uuid

import boto3
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
sqs = boto3.client("sqs", os.getenv("AWS_REGION"))
receive_queue = os.getenv("RECEIVE_QUEUE_URL")


def receive(attempt_id, max_num_messages):
    response = sqs.receive_message(
        QueueUrl=receive_queue,
        ReceiveRequestAttemptId=attempt_id,
        MaxNumberOfMessages=max_num_messages,
        VisibilityTimeout=100,
        WaitTimeSeconds=20,
    )
    if "Messages" not in response:
        return None, True
    messages = [message["Body"] for message in response["Messages"]]
    receipt_handles = [message["ReceiptHandle"] for message in response["Messages"]]
    print(f"{len(messages)} msgs received")
    for receipt_handle in receipt_handles:
        sqs.delete_message(QueueUrl=receive_queue, ReceiptHandle=receipt_handle)
        receipt_handles.remove(receipt_handle)
    print(f"{len(receipt_handles)} msgs deleted")
    return messages, False


def send_to_queue(queue_url, data, message_group_id):
    response = sqs.send_message(
        QueueUrl=queue_url,
        MessageBody=json.dumps(data),
        MessageGroupId=message_group_id,
    )
    return response


# 10 msgs created
for i in range(10):
    sent_response = send_to_queue(
        receive_queue, {"key": i}, message_group_id=os.getenv("MESSAGE_GROUP_ID")
    )

# 10 msgs received
receive(str(uuid.uuid4()), 10)


# Now still 5 msgs are "inflight" and received again
```

Queue configuration

[queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcGZj.png)

I checked prev SO answers which asked me to change non-zero Timeout which I have set.

Comment: And how do you know that you are removing the msg correctly using your code?

Comment: `sqs.delete_message()` returns `200` always. But some msgs are deleted and some are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this `for` loop:

```py
    for receipt_handle in receipt_handles:
        sqs.delete_message(QueueUrl=receive_queue, ReceiptHandle=receipt_handle)
        receipt_handles.remove(receipt_handle)
```

It is attempting to loop through the `receipt_handles` *list* but in each loop it is removing elements from the list. **This is confusing Python.**

For example it starts the loop with element 0. In the next loop, it is operating on element 1 but element 0 was removed from the list so element 1 is actually the original element 2. It is therefore only deleting every second element.

If you do *not* call `remove()`, then it will correctly delete all the messages. You can see this by adding a debugging statement that prints a message whenever a message is deleted.

Comment: Such a basic mistake by me! Thank you